# What is precedence (and associativity) of short-circut logical operators in bash

Tags: bash

My bash manual states that those operators: `(` `)`, `!`, `&&`, `||` go in decreasing order of precedence. Yet the commands:
 `echo 1 || echo 2 && echo 3`
and
 `echo 1 || ( echo 2 && echo 3 )`
give different output.
Am I missing something or is it just the manual being not very precise in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bash manual states:

> Of these list operators, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, followed by `;` and `&`, which have equal precedence.

Unlike all other sane languages, `&&` does not have greater precedence than `||`. Due to left associativity, `echo 1 || echo 2 && echo 3` is parsed as `{echo 1 || echo 2;} && echo 3`.

Comment: How stupid of me, I was looking at `[[ ]]` expression evaluation instead of the Lists section. :/, Thanks.